# Encoder for FLV ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flv, video-encoding

I need to grab desktop and write it to **FLV** video using ffmpeg. I need low CPU usage, but also need text to be recognizable.

Also I see, that many players (f.e. OSFLV) doesnt support H264 FLV.

**1.** Which codec should I choose?

**2.** Which encoder should I use?

See please (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video, 'Support for audio and video compression formats in Flash Player and in Flash Video' TABLE).

If I am wrong somewhere (I am newbie), forgive me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 output.flv`

You can use `-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast` which enables lossless compression. This could be fed into the FLV container. The file size of course would be huge, but you did not mention this as a goal.